# Please explain the C language data structure

Tags: c, types

The result of the values ​of A and B is as follows.

Comment: The reason is implicit integer promotion. There are many similar questions all over SO. Study the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, the type of the expression on the right-hand side is `int`, and the value is -121. In the second case, the type is `uint32_t`, and the value is `uint32_t(-121) == 4294967175`. The latter cannot be precisely represented in a `float`, so it gets rounded.

Comment: I think the subtlety here is that while `uint8_t` is an unsigned type, when used as the left operand of a shift operation, it gets promoted to `int`, not `unsigned int`.  The result of the last signed left shift results in a negative `int` value (and technically, I believe the sign change qualifies as overflow), which remains negative when converted to `float`.